# How to print the contents of enzyme's shallow wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have the following :

```js
import {shallow} from "enzyme" 

const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent/>);
```

how do I see the contents of wrapper?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use [wrapper.debug()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html) to get a string representing the wrapper element, like in:

```
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent/>);
console.log(wrapper.debug());
```

Comment: This changed my life

Comment: what should i do if the console not showing anything?

Comment: @kafinsalim This suggests the wrapper's children may be null or similar. In this case `.debug({verbose: true})` is of no help either. Try something like: `console.log(wrapper.length)` followed by `console.log(wrapper.get(0))`

Comment: console.log('dbg:', JSON.stringify(wrapper.debug(), null, 4));

Answer (score 13):

```
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent/>);
console.log(wrapper.html());
```